# Woocommerce single product tax status trumps WooTax, and Tax Cloud

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I signed up for [Tax Cloud](https://taxcloud.net) and use [Woo Tax](https://wootax.com/) to calculate tax. I am trying to only collect sales tax when shipping to WA. Some of my products' tax status is set to *none* while some is set to *taxable*. When I changed my shipping address on the taxable products the sales tax still showed up, even if the state I chose was listed as *states without sales tax* in tax cloud. When I chose products tax status *none* then I got no sales tax, even if I was shipping to WA.

My question is two-fold: 1) Does tax status *taxable* mean it will add sales tax no matter what?, and 2) what can I do to make sure any and all products get sales tax when shipping to WA?

Answer (score 2):

When using WooTax and TaxCloud, you should leave the WooCommerce "Tax Status" property as "Taxable" (regardless of your local laws - I will explain).

This is because TaxCloud automatically determines the taxable status of what you are selling based upon the Taxability Information Code (TIC) selected (drop-down menu right below the main edit product panel). The TIC along with your orders' origin and destination addresses, and your TaxCloud configuration control where you collect sales tax, and how much sales tax is due and collected.

This way, if you are selling clothing or prewritten software, or any of the other categories of goods options possible, you do not have to know if the item is taxable, exempt, or partially exempt in the jurisdiction of your customer - just select the TIC category, and TaxCloud will handle it correctly for each transaction's unique fact pattern (including sales tax holidays).

So, to answer your questions:

1. Be sure the product Tax Status is set to Taxable, to ensure
   WooCommerce doesn't try to hide the item from TaxCloud for
   calculation.
2. Be sure to set the appropriate TIC code for the
   product ([review all the options](https://TaxCloud.net/tic/)).
3. Within [TaxCloud](https://TaxCloud.net/), in the "Tax States" area, configure where
   you want to collect sales tax.

One more thing... Review your WooCommerce --> Settings --> Tax area to be sure everything is configured correctly:

- Enable Taxes: True (Checked)
- Prices Entered With Tax: No
- Calculate Tax Based On: Customer Shipping Address
- Shipping Tax Class: Based upon cart items
- Rounding: Unchecked
- Additional Tax Classes: [irrelevant - overridden by TaxCloud TIC for each product]
- Display Prices in the Shop: Excluding Tax
- Display Prices During Cart and Checkout: Excluding Tax
- Display Tax Totals:: Itemized

That's all there is to it. Please feel free to call or email TaxCloud customer service if we can help in any way.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for that. So my tax settings match. From the tests I've been running it seems that for products that are taxable, WooCommerce adds sales tax no matter what state it is shipping to; is there something additional I need to set to make sure only items that are shipping to WA get taxed?

Comment: Log into TaxCloud and go to the Tax States area to see where your account is configured to collect sales tax.

Comment: Also, if Automated Compliance is turned on, TaxCloud will also collect sales tax for all 24 of our certifying states (including Washington). With Automated Compliance turned on, TaxCloud handles all of your compliance obligations, including filing, reporting, remittance, and audits, all for free. Automated Compliance is on by default for all TaxCloud accounts because those states pay us to make sales tax compliance easy.

Comment: Okay, so only WA is selected to collect tax, and automated compliance is turned off, so if I set all my products to Taxable then only customers being shipped products to WA will be charged sales tax, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, if the TIC code set for the product is taxable in WA, sales tax will be collected. In all other states, no tax will be collected. We recommend putting your Sales Tax Policy statement (STP) along-side your shipping and returns policies. TaxCloud automatically generates your STP based upon your account settings, you can find it in the "Sales Tax Policy" area. Your STP advises your customers where you collect sales tax, and serves notice that in states where you do not collect tax, they still owe tax. Several states will hold retailers liable for uncollected tax if notice is not given.

Comment: Great, thank you. Last question: Since my TIC is set in Tax Cloud, I don't need to set the TIC for individual products, correct? And there is no TIC setting in Woocommerce I need to set either?

Comment: @vytfla You only need to set TICs on individual products if they are in a different category than your _Default TIC_ configured within your TaxCloud Websites area. See **Step 4** of the [WooTax installation guide](https://wootax.com/installation-guide/)